# What reaction occurs when etching copper to create circuit boards?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, redox

The components used for etching copper are acetic acid, hydrogen peroxide and sodium chloride. I think the equation may be similar to this:

$$\ce{2H3C2O2H + H2O2 + 2NaCl + Cu -> CuCl2 + 2H3C2O2Na + 2H2O}$$

Is this equation correct? There are a lot of bubbles created. What is the gas that is given off?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. I improved the formatting of your post with MathJax. For more information on how to do so yourself, check out the [help], [this meta post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/7475) or [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/444/7475).

Answer (score 1):

Well your equation balances but that isn't the right reaction.

First lets break this down into half cell reactions.

**Oxidation reaction**

> $\ce{Cu_{(s)} <-> Cu^{2+}_{(aq)} + 2e^{-}}$

**Reduction reaction**

> $\ce{H2O2 + 2 H^+ + 2e^{-} ->  2 H2O_{(l)}}$

**Decomposition reaction**

Hydrogen peroxide spontaneously decomposes in acid solution.

> $\ce{2H2O2 ->  2H2O_{(l)} + O2_{(g)}}$

**Stoichiometric reaction between copper and hydrogen peroxide**

So the stoichiometric reaction between copper and hydrogen peroxide is:

> $\ce{H2O2 + 2 H^+ + Cu_{(s)} -> Cu^{2+}_{(aq)} + 2 H2O_{(l)}}$

the $\ce{2 H^+}$ ions come from the vinegar. (Let's use $\ce{HOAc}$ for vinegar).

> $\ce{H2O2 + 2 HOAc + Cu_{(s)} -> Cu^{2+}_{(aq)} + 2OAc^{-} + 2H2O_{(l)}}$

**Sodium chloride's Role**

Finally the role of the $\ce{NaCl}$ plays in the etch. The $\ce{NaCl}$ must be fairly high to drive the $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ to a copper chloride complex. This thus reduces the "free" $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ in solution which keeps the electrochemical potential of copper high so that the solution keeps dissolving copper. (Think of the half-cell copper reaction as if it is in a battery. The voltage of the half-cell would drop as the copper builds up.)

Comment: Before I edit it away amoung another minor typo I found, is there a reason why you write $\ce{Cu+^2}$ rather than $\ce{Cu^2+}$?

Comment: Changed it. Didn't realize that there was such a strong convention, or that anyone would care...

Comment: Will, I'm not aware of any conventions, but I only ever *saw* $\ce{Cu^2+}$ (or $\ce{Cu++}$ from a particularly old biology teacher) so I thought I'ld better ask before doing things wrong ;)

Comment: @Jan - LOL Pauling "The Nature of the Chemical Bond" used the $\ce{Cu^{++}}$ notation so your odd biology teacher was in good company....

Comment: I guess "++" was a good notation until the number of pluses required got larger ;)